# How can I use loops for and if

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop, tapply

This is my example dataset

```
> a
  V1   V2
1 A1 5437
2 A1 5437
3 A1 5437
4 A2 1819
5 A2 1758
6 A2 1212
7 A2 1212
8 A3 1456
```

I want to compute unique values for column V2, so the result will be:

```
A1 1
A2 3
A3 1
```

I have started write my code, but I don't have idea - how should this look like:

```
old_id <- a[1,2]
old_art <- a[2,1]
for (i in nrow(a)){
  if (old_id == a[1,i+2] && old_art == a[i+2,1]){
    new_id[i] <- old_id[1,i+2]
    new_art[i] <- i
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

I know very simple solution like:

```
tapply(a[,2], a[,1], function(t) length(unique(t)))
```

but my task is to use loop function - probably for and if

Comment: Barranka you have to believe me this isn't homework. Can you help me change function tapply on loop ?

Comment: I have tried to use mapreduce (I wrote other question about this, but people didn't understand my intention). What's more I can't use in mapreduce function tapply, I have to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework. But `for` loops run through all elements in the vector on the right hand side of `in`. This also means that your `for` loop will increment automatically and so you don't need `i <- i+1`.

Hence, your `for` loop should look like this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  < your code >
}
# i <- i + 1 # No need for this!
```

Notice  `i in 1:nrow(a)` and no `i in nrow(a)`. I haven't checked your code, only your `for`syntax.
Remember, `for` loops are just functions; so

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
}
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
```

is the same as

```
`for`(i, 1:3, print(i))
#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
```

See `?"for"`.

Comment: Thx for this suggestions (I changed in my code this scrap of my code), but still can't write this code...

Answer (score 0):

Your question, specifically, concerns the ussage of `for` and `if`. Here is my approach:

- You can define `for` in two forms: the "classic C style" and the "vector style".

The "classic C style" would be something like this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= nrow(a); i = i + 1) {
    # Your code goes here
}
```

The "vector style" would be something like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    # Your code goes here
}
```

Notice that, in both cases, the `for` statement is the one that increments the value of `i`. Also, remember that in R the starting index is one (unlike many C-like languages, where the starting index is usually zero).

As for your `if` statement, R uses only one `&` for `and` (and only one `|` for `or`), so your `if` statement should be something like this:

```
if(old_id == a[1,i+2] & old_art == a[i+2,1]) {
    # More code here
}
```

Finally, if you want to debug your code, check [this link](http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/murdoch/software/debuggingR/debug.shtml).